# Display Single point on google material line chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization, google-loader

If I have a single data row like this:

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'User');

  data.addRows([
    [new Date(), 41],
  ]);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Active Users',
    },
    width: 900,
    height: 500
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

How to display a point in such kind of situation? Right now, the point is there but it is not highlighted.This problem is only in material chart not in classic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the option for `pointSize` needs to be set for a single row of data

however, it is among the several options that do not work on *Material* charts
see this issue --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity #2143](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

instead, recommend using *Core* chart, with following option...

`theme: 'material'`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'User');

  data.addRows([
    [new Date(), 41],
  ]);

  var options = {
    height: 500,
    theme: 'material',
    title: 'Active Users',
    width: 900
  };

  if (data.getNumberOfRows() === 1) {
    options.pointSize = 5;
  }

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: can I set options explicitly? Suppose, If there is a single row then I can add pointSize : 5 otherwise not.

Comment: note: a bug in the `'current'` version of google charts prevents a single row from being displayed, which was not an issue when the above answer was written, for more info, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54422077/5090771)