# Google chart - remove rows from data.cache JSFiddle

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Task is to show only last 5 records in google chart. As you move slider, on end, data is adding.
Records are from some "slider", later will be replaced with some live senzor data.

hAxis is timestamp so i don't know how to use:

```
 viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
                // viewWindow: {
                //   min: 0,
                //   max: 4
                // },
```

Sow question is how to remove rows from data cache?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejovrh2/k59u6be3/17/): https://jsfiddle.net/ejovrh2/k59u6be3/17/

Answer (score 1):

when using timestamp on the x-axis,
you can use a date object directly, no need to convert to a string.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ["Date", "level"],
  [new Date(), level],
]);
```

and to control the range displayed on the x-axis,
`viewWindow` min & max should be the same data type.
in this case, a date.

```
viewWindow: {
  min: new Date(2020, 10, 1),
  max: new Date(2020, 10, 30)
},
```

Comment: Ok this is principle. But..
Goal is to display last 5 records, in future don't know how often senzor will throw data so I can't limit window with date or time (i could do something like max is now and min is now - x days). So result in my fiddle is some type of array and I need to remove first record.

Comment: you can use data table method [getColumnRange](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getColumnRange) to determine the min & max dates from the data table...

Comment: I get result object object...
Any way thanks for your time. I will try tomorrow.

Comment: yes, the method returns an object, with properties for min & max. [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54422077/5090771) that uses the method...

Answer (score 0):

As @WhiteHat said you can use data.getColumnRange and then extract min&max.

In my case I need to show just last few records no matter dates.
So I needed this part of code:

```
data.removeRow(0);
```

Answer

```
    // when data is populated with 4 rows, remove first one [0]
    if (data.cache.length>4){
    data.removeRow(0); 
   // just to see range and how is removing first element
    var dateRange = data.getColumnRange(0);
    console.log(dateRange);
    }
```

Finnish [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejovrh2/k59u6be3/54/)